# java vector recursion solution generating subsets have different results

Tags: java, c++, recursion, vector

I want to generate all subsets of a set from 0 to n.

My code works successfully in c++, but in Java I've got different result

---

My code in c++:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
vector <vector<int>> v;
vector <int> u;
int n,i,j;
void f(vector <int> m,int k){
    if(k==n+1){v.push_back(m);return;}
    f(m,k+1);
    m.push_back(k);
    f(m,k+1);
}
int main() {
    cin>>n;
    f(u,0);
    for(i=0;i<v.size();i++){
        for(j=0;j<v[i].size();j++)cout<<v[i][j]<<' ';
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

input in c++: 2 
output: 

2 
1 
1 2 
0 
0 2 
0 1 
0 1 2 
and my code in Java:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static int c=0,j,i,n,l,r,x;
    public static Vector <Vector<Integer>> v = new Vector();

    public static void f(Vector <Integer> m,int k){
        if (k==n+1) {v.add(m);return;}
        f(m,k+1);
        m.add(k);
        f(m,k+1);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        n=scan.nextInt();
        Vector<Integer> u = new Vector<Integer>();
        f(u,0);
        for(i=0;i<v.size();i++){
            for(int j:v.get(i))System.out.print(j+" ");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

input in Java: 2 
output:
2 1 2 0 2 1 2 
2 1 2 0 2 1 2 
2 1 2 0 2 1 2 
2 1 2 0 2 1 2 
2 1 2 0 2 1 2 
2 1 2 0 2 1 2 
2 1 2 0 2 1 2 
2 1 2 0 2 1 2 
As you see code in java is based on same logic but I cannot understand why java version gives me wrong result.

Comment: How are the results different?

Comment: you should write what it suppose to do. What is expected behavior.

Comment: Could you provide the results from both applications?  

I'd like to give also just a little tip :-) This code is hard to read due to those mysterious variable names `j,i,n,l,r,x,u` :-)  I believe that if you could give some meaningful names to just some of those vars, you could maybe even solve your problem by yourself ;-)

Comment: also in C++ you what this: `void f(vector <int>& m,int k)` or in Java you should create a copy of array before `f` is called.

Comment: Can you explain which output you are expecting? I understand that is frustrating when you fully understand your code, but it will help others understand your perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As you see code in java is based on same logic but I cannot Understand Why java code gives me wrong result

There is a big difference between **C++** and **Java** here. In **C++**, unless you explicitly use `vector<int> & v` to use the same *vector*, it will automatically make a copy while in **Java** you have to explicitly do the copy yourself. **Java** uses *pass-by-value* mechanism and you only created one vector and then use it all the way which actually using the same **vector**.

Your problem lies: using the same **vector** to collect the elements all the way through.

To solve this problem, you should create a new `vector` to store the elements when passing in the method as:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static int c = 0, j, i, n, l, r, x;
    public static Vector<Vector<Integer>> v = new Vector();

    // each combination of the elements should have an independent vector;
    public static void f(Vector<Integer> m, int k) {
        if (k == n + 1) {
            v.add(m);
            return;
        } // the unique vector;
        f(new Vector<>(m), k + 1); // create a new vector to store the elements;
        m.add(k);
        f(new Vector<>(m), k + 1); // same logic applied here;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        n = scan.nextInt();
        Vector<Integer> u = new Vector<Integer>();
        f(new Vector<>(), 0);
        for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
            for (int j : v.get(i)) System.out.print(j + " ");
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output can be:

```
3

3 
2 
2 3 
1 
1 3 
1 2 
1 2 3 
0 
0 3 
0 2 
0 2 3 
0 1 
0 1 3 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3
```

Comment: @SandroSkhirtladze Hahah, my pleasure...upvote it? If it's good for your problem...thank you